# Will threads from ExecutorService be guaranteed to update the locally declared concurrent hashmap?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, executorservice

```
public void test() {

    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        integers.add(i);
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ExecutorService pool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
    try {
        pool.submit(() -> integers.parallelStream().forEach(integer -> {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println("Foo " + name);
            cache.put(integer, integer);
        })).get();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    System.out.println(cache);
}
```

I read that you will need to have volatile variable to ensure updates to a variable are propagated predictably to other thread. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html#variable-visibility-problems

In this test method I cannot declare the "cache" concurrent hashmap as a "volatile" variable since it is a local variable not an instance variable. When the code gets to System.out.println(cache) line, will it guaranteed that my main thread will see all the values that were added to "cache" by ExecutorService threads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your code will work fine. The `ConcurrentHashMap` guarantees that all the inserted mappings will happen in a thread-safe manner.

You don't need to care about `pool` and `cache` -- they're effectively final variables, and as such, their values once set at construction time (before you start any multi-threaded code) won't change anymore.

What may be confusing you is that when dealing with non-final fields, you may need to mark them as `volatile` if you intend to change them and to be sure that the change is correctly propagated across threads. But as said above, notice how in this case the value of `pool` and `caches` is never changed.

Comment: I missed out the idea of "effectively final" for Java 8. For those who are interested, this is an article that I found. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-is-effectively-final-variable-of.html. In Addition, I've also found this article that explains why final variables guaranteed visibility for other threads. https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml

Comment: @howly the special guarantees of `final` variables are not needed here. You are initializing the `cache` before initiating any asynchronous action and hence, the value will be visible to them regardless of what kind of variable you are using. As this answer says, visibility issues can only arise if you *change* the variable after the asynchronous actions have been commenced. But in that case, you can run into far more problems than visibility, so not even declaring it `volatile` will solve all problems.

Comment: @Holger Aren't we writing new values into the concurrent hashmap though. So I guess final guarantee is only needed if we are re-assigning?

Comment: @howly the modifications made to the map after the background threads have been started, are not affected by the special final field guarantees. They work, because `ConcurrentHashMap` provides guarantees for concurrent updates. With an ordinary `HashMap`, this wouldn’t work and no modifier added to its reference variable could change that.